# Random url generator, but ensure results are unique

Tags: python

I found myself perusing the web in search for a URL/string generator that mimics that of twitch's clips random URL schema. See [here](https://twitter.com/vetoed/status/842577956950163456?lang=en) for an example of what I mean. I happened to find [readable-url](https://github.com/sharadbhat/ReadableURL) but alas it's for `npm`. So... In efforts to make this available to Python users I'm making one for us! Actually I already made it and it's in my github [now](https://github.com/Jabbey92/sentence-url).

My dilemma is I want to ensure all strings are unique for every generated response. Full code is below.

```
from random import choice, sample

vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}

with open("words/adjectives.txt") as adjs_file:
  adjectives = adjs_file.read().split()
with open("words/nouns.txt") as words_file:
  nouns = words_file.read().split()

class SentenceURL:

    def __init__(self, word_count = 3, capitalize = True, seperator = ''):
        self.word_count = word_count
        self.capitalize = capitalize
        self.seperator = seperator

    def generate():
        """Generates readable URLs like Twitch's clips"""

        if self.word_count < 2:
            raise ValueError('Minimum value expected: 2')
        elif self.word_count > 10:
            raise ValueError('Maximum value expected: 10')

        noun = choice(nouns)
        word_list = []

        if self.word_count > 3:
            if noun in vowels:
                word_list = ['an']
            else:
                word_list = [choice(('a', 'the'))]

        word_list.extend(sample(adjectives, k = self.word_count-1))

        if self.word_count > 4:
            word_list.insert(2, 'and')

        word_list.append(noun)

        if self.capitalize:
            word_list = map(str.title, word_list)

        return self.seperator.join(word_list)
```

So my initial thought is to just keep a running set of previously used strings and see if the new one is in the set and if it is then generate another one, this would be easy to implement, but it seems very inefficient. What other options do I have? Thanks!

Comment: Stick a UUID in it.  (OK, so not *all* of the URL will be readable.)

Comment: I'm trying to emulate twitch.tv's generator, as they doesn't have any UUID in them. See https://twitter.com/vetoed/status/842577956950163456?lang=en. I will include in my question

Comment: If you're less concerned about space efficiency than about speed efficiency, you could always pre-generate all possible combinations once and store them in a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), then `pop` one at a time. No lookups, quick append/pop operations

Comment: Also, given that you state your code works and you just want to improve it, you might ask this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought about that. Should I delete this one if I ask on CR?